# Javascript - calling an external function as a property of an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have an array of objects, at this moment there is just one object inside. In this object i have a function that elaborate some properties of the same object.
The function is processed outside the array, but the result is NaN, i dont know how pass correctly the values..

Example

```
let arrayObj = [{
  number1: 1,
  number2: 2,
  sum: sum(this.number1 , this.number2)
}
]

function sum(n1, n2) {
  return console.log(n1 + n2);
}
```

Result: NaN.

```
for (let i in arrayObj){
  console.log(arrayObj[i])
}
```

Result: {number1: 1, number2: 2, sum: undefined}

Comment: The property value does not have `this` bound to the object yet.

Comment: @TravisJ if function sum() was an arrow function, would it work?

Comment: No @ozgur, the issue is when the object's this binding is assigned, and is unrelated to the sum function call.

Comment: @TravisJ thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add that property to the object when you are iterating over it.

```
const arrayObj = [{
    number1: 1,
    number2: 2,
}];

function sum(n1, n2) {
  return n1 + n2;
}

for (let i in arrayObj){
  arrayObj[i].sum = sum(arrayObj[i].number1, arrayObj[i].number2)
  console.log(arrayObj[i])
}
```

Comment: Glad to help friend

Answer (score 3):

If you want a fully usable object during object creation, then use a Function object.

```js
let arrayObj = [new function(){
  this.number1 = 1;
  this.number2 = 2;
  this.sum = sum(this.number1 , this.number2)
}]

// minor edit to return the sum instead of returning the result of the console log
function sum(n1, n2) {
  console.log(n1 + n2);
  return n1 + n2;
}

for (let i in arrayObj){
  console.log(arrayObj[i])
}
```

However, if you are in need of this function at a later time, and want it accessible for all of those objects, then stop using anonymous objects and create an actual class or prototype.

Prototype:

```js
function Point(number1, number2){
 this.number1 = number1;
 this.number2 = number2;
}
Point.prototype.sum = function(){
 return this.number1 + this.number2;
}

let arrayObj = [
 new Point(1,2),
 new Point(3,4),
 new Point(15,30)
];

for (let i in arrayObj){
  console.log(arrayObj[i].sum())
}
```

Class:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(number1, number2){
    this.number1 = number1;
    this.number2 = number2;
  }
  get sum(){
      return this.number1 + this.number2;
  }
}

let arrayObj = [
 new Point(1,2),
 new Point(3,4),
 new Point(15,30)
];

for (let i in arrayObj){
  console.log(arrayObj[i].sum)
}
```

Comment: In this case i cant add a similary obj, its doesnt work.

let arrayObj = [new function(){
...
},
{
  this.number1 = 10;
  this.number2 = 20;
  this.sum = sum(this.number1 , this.number2)
}]

Well, maybe is not not correct my approach to the problem. I want to creato an external function to call in different obj and pass different parameters

Comment: @Fedoro - You would create a new function for each object you wish to have during creation. So in your example in your comment here, you would need a new function in both spaces. If you wish to have a value passed in, you can do so in the function call, although it gets a little different to setup. If you expand on your situation a little, I could show that as well.

Comment: @Fedoro - If you intend to have more structure to objects, then make sure the logic is in the right place. Adding the sum property to the object at a later time, as shown in Ori's answer, is inefficient (prototypes and classes only have their logic stored once in the interpreter), and is also bad design (as your logic is now located at the point of calling instead of at the point of creating). Instead, use a class or prototype.

Answer (score 1):

There has a simple solution. you can put an instant function in your sum property and under that function, send the other required values of the object by converting them into variables. See below:

```
function sum(n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}
const arrayObj = [{
        'number1': 1,
        'number2': 2,
        'sum': function () {
            let num1 = this.number1, num2 = this.number2;
            return sum(num1, num2);
        }
    }];

console.log(arrayObj.sum())
```

Comment: It will be great to add good formatting for easy readability

Comment: I have nicely formatted the code. I hope, it will help others to understand the code easily. By the way, I am a new contributor to StackOverflow. Thanks for your support.

one more thing, if you want to fetch the sum from this object. you should call like arrayObj.sum() because the sum is now a function.

Comment: You should definitely add this comment in the answer as it is very unlikely that someone will read comment section.

Comment: This is simply a more convoluted version of the [answer provided by rombie18](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974297/6036546).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a seperate function, you can also write the sum function in the object itself. Now when you access the sum field in your object, it will sum the two values and return it.

```
let arrayObj = [{
    number1: 1,
    number2: 2,
    sum: function() {
        return this.number1 + this.number2;
    }
}]

console.log(arrayObj[0].sum());
```

Comment: This requires the function to be called though, and will not assign the value during object creation.

Comment: I want to separete the function to call it in the others objects, with others parameters

Comment: In that case the answer from Travis is more appropriate indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another interesting solution (I don't remember where I had found it.) for this problem. Using *getter function* of javascript the problem can solve easily.You can use this in your object directly to use the external function. If a property (key) of an object se the external function to get a value and it have to behave like normal **"key:value"** pair (not being a method/function), then the getter function is the best way to use to get the value. To know more about it please [read it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```js
function sum(n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}
const arrayObj = 
      {
        get sum() {return sum(this.number1, this.number2)},
        number1: 1,
        number2: 2,
        number3: 4,
        get totalsum() {return sum(this.sum, this.number3)} //using the sum property (that used external function) in another property.
      };


console.log(arrayObj);
console.log('the sum of '+arrayObj.number1+' & '+arrayObj.number2+' is: '+arrayObj.sum); 

console.log('the sum of '+arrayObj.sum+' & '+arrayObj.number3+' is: '+arrayObj.totalsum);
```